# Import packages and running toy example tests

Tags: python, import

I am currently organizing my files and folders as follows:

```
main.py
modules
|- __init__.py
|- x.py
|- y.py
```

The code in each file are:

```
# main.py
from modules.x import X
```

```
# modules/x.py
from modules.y import Y
class X():
  # etc...

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # testing of class X here
```

```
# modules/y.py
class Y():
  # etc...
```

From the root folder, it is okay to run `python main.py`, however it is not okay to run `python modules/x.py` since it will show `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'`.

What I am trying to do is to test if class X functions well as I want (using some toy examples) while I can still use main.py to run the real task using class X.

I know I can `from .y import Y` instead to run `python modules/x.py` but that means I cannot run `python main.py`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You need to put a `__init__.py` file in your modules folder for it to be recognized as a python `module`. Only then can you import using `from modules.y import Y`

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention that I already did that and it's not the cause. If I run `python modules/x.py` it means I am running it in `cwd() = modules` and therefore there is no `modules` folder inside it anymore. I can do `from .y import Y` instead but that would mean I cannot run `python main.py` anymore.